# Dynamic Numbering based on date in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

Hello buddy i've some problem with numbering, i want to make numbering for reference number which value will back into 1 when the year changed... How could i do that ? any idea ?

```
No. <?php echo $keluhan->id ?>/PTKP EXT/PBT/<?php echo $bulan[date('n')]?>/<?php echo date('Y')?>
```

I want to change `$keluhan->id` with dynamic number start with 1 and start again from 1 if the year changed **(2017 into 2018)**